# Best single word for 'Developer Hierarchy'

Tags: single-word-requests

Can anyone suggest a single word that convey the meaning '**hierarchy of developers**'?

Comment: Can you give a context? Do you mean a chain of command when employed, or like a work chain gang of prisoners? Or something else?

Comment: work chain of developers

Comment: Actually i need a single word for 'Work chain of developers/designers

Comment: Developers work in chains now? I pity them.

Comment: "Hierarchy" comes to mind, but it is more generic than work-specific, I guess.  Plus it connotes an up-down relationship among people, with the "superiors" above, and the "inferiors" below.  Not very egalitarian, which is probably what you are looking for, yes?

Comment: @RegDwighт: Tell me about it. :^)

Comment: Mahesh, the phrase "Work Chain" doesn't mean anything specific to me - do you mean "sequence of instructions passed to developers", "hierarchy of developers engaged in work", "sequence in which each developer will need to do work" or something else?

Comment: 'Chain of command' is the phrase used in the military for how orders are passed from superiors down to supporters. But are you talking a bout a pipeline or assembly line, where one person does a little something and then that is passed on to the next person to do a little something extra, all under one supervisor?

Comment: @MarkBannister ya.. somewhat like "hierarchy of developers engaged in work".

Comment: Mahash: When people clamor for more context in comments, you need to **edit your question**, not answer with more comments. People finding this question for the first time shouldn't need to read through an entire conversation just to figure out what you're asking about. In this case, add a short paragraph that describes what a "work chain" is; otherwise – who knows? You could be referring to something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5IxUI.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence of steps where a piece of work goes through a number of treatments by different people — for example, an request for a quotation which is received, estimated, passed for approval, sent out, results in an order which is received... etc — can be called a ***workflow***.

This isn't particularly hierarchical, although generally such a process will travel up and down the hierarchy (receipt; up to estimating; up to approver; back down to be sent out).

> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/workflow?q=workflow)
>
> **workflow** *noun*
>
> the sequence of industrial, administrative, or other processes through which a piece of work passes from initiation to completion.

Answer (score 3):

*[Pipeline](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pipeline#Noun)*, in its sense “a channel (either physical or logical) by which information is transmitted sequentially...” may serve, as may also terms like 
 *[assembly line](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assembly_line#Noun)* (“A system of workers and machinery in which a product is assembled in a series of consecutive operations”),  *production line*, and *[process](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/process#Noun)*, in one or more of its senses like “A series of events to produce a result”,  “A set of procedures used to produce a product”, and “A path [or] succession of states through which a system passes”.

None of these terms specifically mean “work chain”, but within a description of how your shop completes projects may suggest that the work goes through a planned series of steps.